# retrieve application/json document with twill/mechanize in authenticated session

Tags: python, json, mechanize, twill

I need to retrieve a document with MIME type "application/json". I'm using twill to log in to a site and when I attempt to `go` to the URL pointing to the JSON document and `show` it, I get this message:

```
'The HTTP header field "Accept" with value "text/html; */*" could not be parsed.'
```

I have tried changing the "Accept" field to "application/json" but still no dice.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means the answer I'm looking for, but [zope.testbrowser](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.testbrowser) will do what I want.

The interface is slightly more complicated than twill, but not by much.

Still looking for a twill solution!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have `Accept: text/html; */*` which seems syntactically wrong to me: per [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z3), the syntax is

```
    <field>  =    Accept: <entry> *[ , <entry> ]
    <entry>  =    <content type> *[ ; <param> ]
    <param>  =    <attr> = <float>
    <attr>   =    q / mxs / mxb
    <float>  =    <ANSI-C floating point text represntation>
```

so that `*/*`, since it follows a semicolon rather than a comma, *should* be a `<param>`, but not in fact of the form `<attr> = <float>`.  Did you mean to have a `q=something,` after the semicolon, and forgot to give it?  Else, just `text/html, */*` -- i.e., with a comma, not a semicolon -- seems to be the right syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look in to this.